# Django Channels: WebSocket messages are not sent in production

Tags: django, django-channels, uvicorn

I have Django server which uses WebSockets to send real time updates to web clients. This is all running perfectly fine locally (with `manage.py runserver`), but in production I am running into the problem that most messages are simply not sent at all. I test this by opening two browsers, making a change in one, which should then be reflected in the other browser. Like I said, this all works locally, but not in production. In production *some* WebSocket messages are sent by the server and received by the web client, but maybe 20% or so? The rest is just not sent at all.

```py
# /websockets/__init__.py

import logging
from asgiref.sync import async_to_sync
from channels.layers import get_channel_layer
from djangorestframework_camel_case.util import camelize

logger = logging.getLogger("django.server.ws.critical-notes")


def ws_send(model_type, action, model_data, user_ids):
    logger.info(f"Called ws_send for model {model_type}, action {action}, user_ids: {user_ids}")

    channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
    for user_id in user_ids:
        group_name = f"user-{user_id}"
        async_to_sync(channel_layer.group_send)(
            group_name,
            {
                "type": "send.data",  # this calls Consumer.send_data
                "data": {"type": model_type, "action": action, "model": camelize(model_data)},
            },
        )
```

```py
# /websockets/consumers.py

import logging
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer
from channels.db import database_sync_to_async
from django.db import close_old_connections
from knox.auth import TokenAuthentication

logger = logging.getLogger("django.server.ws.critical-notes")


class Consumer(AsyncJsonWebsocketConsumer):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(args, kwargs)
        self.group_name = None

    @database_sync_to_async
    def get_user(self, token):
        try:
            auth = TokenAuthentication()
            user, auth_token = auth.authenticate_credentials(token.encode("utf-8"))
            return user
        except Exception as e:
            logger.warning("User not found:", e)
            return None

    # User can authenticate by sending a JSON message containing a token
    async def receive_json(self, content, **kwargs):
        token = content["token"]
        if token is None:
            return

        user = await self.get_user(token)
        close_old_connections()

        if user is not None:
            self.group_name = f"user-{user.pk}"
            logger.info(f"WS connected to {self.group_name}")
            await self.channel_layer.group_add(self.group_name, self.channel_name)

    # This gets called by /websockets/__init__.py sending an event with type "send.data"
    async def send_data(self, event):
        data = event["data"]
        logger.info(f"Sending event to WS user {self.group_name}: {data}")
        await self.send_json(content=data)

    # Clean up on disconnect
    async def disconnect(self, close_code):
        if self.group_name is not None:
            logger.info(f"WS disconnected: {self.group_name}")
            await self.channel_layer.group_discard(self.group_name, self.channel_name)

        await self.close()
```

```py
# /websockets/routing.py

from django.urls import re_path

from .consumers import Consumer

websocket_urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r"ws", Consumer.as_asgi()),
]
```

With all this in place, I can do something like this in my Django views and models:

```py
from websockets import ws_send
ws_send("model_name", "create", data, user_ids)
```

To let these user_ids know that a certain model was created, with the data.

When I look at the server logs, I can see that `Called ws_send for model` is consistently logged, but then the `Sending event to WS user` log message is missing.

Some server setup info:

```py
# settings.py

ASGI_APPLICATION = "criticalnotes.asgi.application"
WSGI_APPLICATION = "criticalnotes.wsgi.application"
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {"default": {"BACKEND": "channels.layers.InMemoryChannelLayer"}}
```

```py
# asgi.py

import os
import django

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "criticalnotes.settings")
django.setup()

from channels.routing import ProtocolTypeRouter, URLRouter
from django.core.asgi import get_asgi_application

import criticalnotes.websockets.routing

application = ProtocolTypeRouter(
    {
        "http": get_asgi_application(),
        "websocket": URLRouter(criticalnotes.websockets.routing.websocket_urlpatterns),
    }
)
```

I'm using Nginx with uvicorn on the server:

```
# /etc/systemd/system/api.critical-notes.com.service

[Unit]
Description=api.critical-notes.com

[Service]
User=criticalnotes
Group=criticalnotes
Environment="PYTHONPATH=/opt/api"
ExecStart=/opt/api/env/bin/uvicorn criticalnotes.asgi:application --log-level warning --workers 4 --uds /tmp/uvicorn.sock

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/api.critical-notes.com

server {
    server_name api.critical-notes.com;
    root /var/www/api.critical-notes.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_buffering off;
        proxy_pass http://uvicorn;
    }

    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.critical-notes.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.critical-notes.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = api.critical-notes.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

    server_name api.critical-notes.com;
    listen 80;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}

map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    '' close;
}

upstream uvicorn {
    server unix:/tmp/uvicorn.sock;
}
```

I'm at a loss, I don't understand why everything works perfectly locally, but not in production. It's a huge problem for my users: real times updates simply do not work most of the time :(

Version info: Channels 3.0.4 and Django 3.2.8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out I really needed to switch to `channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer` as the channel backend, instead of using `InMemoryChannelLayer`.

Comment: It solves the problem . But any idea why it solves the problem?

Comment: My guess is because uvicorn is run with multiple workers. But I also tried running uvicorn with only one worker and then it still didn't work, so I am not really sure..

Answer (score -1):

You need to add new location to serve your websocket resources in nginx configuration. Change your consumer route to something like `/ws/updates`.

```
     location /ws/ {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "Upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass http://uvicorn;
    }
```

This way you could access the consumer updates at `/ws/updates`. Your api will be served at `/` while your websocket will be served at `/ws`.

Comment: Can you explain how that would fix things? Because I can connect to `wss://api.critical-notes.com/ws` just fine, I can send messages to the websocket server (to login with a token), and I do receive *some* messages.

Comment: I did try your suggestion, but it didn't make any difference.